# Get dependencies of POM with activated profiles

Tags: java, maven

Say I have a (parent) pom with some profiles which contain dependencies. My aim is to get a list of these dependencies (by Aether or other methods accessible from java). The usual `getDependencies` of Aether seems to ignore profiles -- at least I cannot find any way to activate them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for the dependencies just contained in the `<profile>` section, the list of all direct dependencies including active profiles, or the list of all resolved dependencies (+ transitive) including active profiles?

Comment: The main purpose is to gather the (direct) dependencies that are specified in the profiles of a parent pom. The reason is that usually all profiles are activated and I need the complete list of dependencies of the parent pom for an automatically generated (project) pom.